# How do I consume -D variables in build.scala using SBT?

Tags: scala, sbt

I have a build.scala file that has a dependency that looks like this:

```
"com.example" % "core" % "2.0" classifier "full-unstable"
```

This pulls in a JAR with the classifier of full-unstable

What I need to do is specify either "unstable" or "stable" to SBT (using a -D I presume) from Jenkins (the build server) to change the classifier. If variable substitution worked like it does in Maven, the dependency would look like:

```
"com.example" % "core" % "2.0" classifier "full-${branch}"
```

And I would do "-Dbranch=unstable" or "-Dbranch=stable"

I'm very unclear how I do this with SBT and a build.scala file.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can simply access `sys.props`: "A bidirectional, mutable Map representing the current system Properties."
So, you can do something like this:

```
val branch = "full-" + sys.props.getOrElse("branch", "unstable")
"com.example" % "core" % "2.0" classifier branch
```

If you want to have more advanced custom properties from file in your `Build.scala`:

```
import java.io.{BufferedReader, InputStreamReader, FileInputStream, File}
import java.nio.charset.Charset
import java.util.Properties

object MyBuild extends Build {

  // updates system props (mutable map of props)
  loadSystemProperties("project/myproj.build.properties")

  def loadSystemProperties(fileName: String): Unit = {
    import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
    val file = new File(fileName)
    if (file.exists()) {
      println("Loading system properties from file `" + fileName + "`")
      val in = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file), "UTF-8")
      val props = new Properties
      props.load(in)
      in.close()
      sys.props ++ props.asScala
    }
  }

  // to test try:
  println(sys.props.getOrElse("branch", "unstable"))
}
```

SBT is more powerful than Maven because you can simply write Scala code if you need something very custom. You would want to use `Build.scala` instead of `build.sbt` in such case.

p.s `myproj.build.properties` file looks like this for example:

```
sbt.version=0.13.1

scalaVersion=2.10.4

parallelExecution=true

branch=stable
```

Comment: doesn't SBT already read in build.properties out of the box that you have to do it manually? or I remember wrong.

Comment: yes it does. I was showing an example of additional `build.properties` file that you might have for Jenkins and which can also be auto generated by Jenkins pre-build step. I'll rename the filename in the example to avoid confusion.